# Parsing xml file in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I am currently trying to parse meteorologic xml files with R. I found a lot of answers on the web but it seems that my file is a bit particular:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<current>
  <city id="2643743" name="London">
    <coord lon="-0.13" lat="51.51"/>
    <country>GB</country>
    <sun rise="2015-02-09T07:24:47" set="2015-02-09T17:04:38"/>
  </city>
  <temperature value="281.05" min="281.05" max="281.05" unit="kelvin"/>
  <humidity value="80" unit="%"/>
  <pressure value="1033.5" unit="hPa"/>
  <wind>
    <speed value="1" name="Calm"/>
    <direction value="225" code="SW" name="Southwest"/>
  </wind>
  <clouds value="88" name="overcast clouds"/>
  <visibility/>
  <precipitation mode="no"/>
  <weather number="804" value="overcast clouds" icon="04d"/>
  <lastupdate value="2015-02-09T15:55:20"/>
</current>
```

If the delimiters were written as usual, for the coordinates for example :

```
<coord>
   <lon> "-0.13" </lon> 
   <lat> "51.51" </lat>
</coord>
```

It would not be a problem. However, in my case, I have some trouble parsing the tree.
I especially want to have the following information: value for the temperature, for the clouds and for the humidity. So far, I just managed to get a table with the headers and nothing for the values.

I looked over the internet to find the solution but I haven't found anything that looks like my XML file.

Does anyone has had to deal with a similar problem before?

My R code for the parser is the following in case that could help :).

```
files <- list.files(path="~/Desktop/R code/files", recursive="true") 

parse_xml <-function(FileName) {
  doc1 <- xmlParse(paste("~/Desktop/R code/files",FileName,sep="/")) 
  doc <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc1,"//current"))[c("temperature","humidity","clouds")] 

} 

Data <- ldply(files, parse_xml)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the original web-scraping intent of the `rvest` package, it also works well for XML crunching and is generally easier to grok vs the xpath*Apply`s.

```
library(XML)
library(rvest)

dat <- xmlParse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<current>
  <city id="2643743" name="London">
    <coord lon="-0.13" lat="51.51"/>
    <country>GB</country>
    <sun rise="2015-02-09T07:24:47" set="2015-02-09T17:04:38"/>
  </city>
  <temperature value="281.05" min="281.05" max="281.05" unit="kelvin"/>
  <humidity value="80" unit="%"/>
  <pressure value="1033.5" unit="hPa"/>
  <wind>
    <speed value="1" name="Calm"/>
    <direction value="225" code="SW" name="Southwest"/>
  </wind>
  <clouds value="88" name="overcast clouds"/>
  <visibility/>
  <precipitation mode="no"/>
  <weather number="804" value="overcast clouds" icon="04d"/>
  <lastupdate value="2015-02-09T15:55:20"/>
</current>')

dat %>% xml_nodes(xpath="/current/temperature") %>% xml_attr("value")
## [1] "281.05"

dat %>% xml_nodes(xpath="/current/temperature") %>% xml_attr("min")
## [1] "281.05"

dat %>% xml_nodes(xpath="/current/temperature") %>% xml_attr("max")
## [1] "281.05"

dat %>% xml_nodes(xpath="/current/temperature") %>% xml_attr("unit")
## [1] "kelvin"

dat %>% xml_nodes(xpath="/current/clouds") %>% xml_attr("value")
## [1] "88"

dat %>% xml_nodes(xpath="/current/clouds") %>% xml_attr("name")
## [1] "overcast clouds"
```

You can also use traditional syntax with those calls, too:

```
xml_attr(xml_nodes(dat, xpath="/current/temperature"), "value")
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for. rvest package is way easier to use than XML package for these small operations. Thank you very much.